# Subtotal, Sumproduct, Multiple Criteria & Offset using a Dynamic Range

Tags: excel, dynamic, subtotal

My current WORKING formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WBS!$P$15:$P$65002=WBS!$A$13)*(WBS!$Q$15:$Q$65002=WBS!$AJ3),WBS!$AK$15:$AK$65002)
```

I want to convert this formula to total filtered cells only. This is what I have (NOT WORKING) so far:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($AK15,ROW($AK15:$AK65000)-ROW(AK15),,1 WBS!$P$15:$P$65002=WBS!$A$13)*(WBS!$Q$15:$Q$65002=WBS!$AJ3))
```

Then, if you know how to convert this to grab from dynamic ranges, that would be awesome!

Comment: OMG!  You did it!  You're awesome!!!  I've been trying for days to figure this out.  Thank you, Sir.  I don't suppose you could amble over to my other question about Dynamic Ranges?  lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(WBS!$AK$15,ROW(WBS!$AK$15:$AK$65002)-ROW(WBS!$AK$15),,,1)),--(WBS!$P$15:$P$65002=WBS!$A$13),--(WBS!$Q$15:$Q$65002=WBS!$AJ3))
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert this in VBA?  I've been trying to understand what I have read so far but...  not working!

Comment: @LoriLee You will need to create a new question for that because it requires a different answer.  You'll need to include what code you've tried so far.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well, I'm SOL 'cause I don't understand it enough to know what I am looking at.  Thanks anyway!